# Why does Apart not give full solution?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

Why does `Apart` not give full solutions? E.g.:

```
ApartSquareFree[x/(x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5), x]
1/(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)
```

Comment: What would you like it to give?

Comment: a sum of terms with $a_{ij}/(x-x_i)^j$ (or $(b_{ij}x+c_{ij})/(x-z_i)^j(x-\bar{z_i})^j$)

Answer (score 4):

This works for your specific problem:

```
Clear[y]
y = x/(x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5);
ApartSquareFree[
 Numerator[y]/Factor[Denominator[y], Extension -> GoldenRatio]]
```

$\frac{2 x+\sqrt{5}+1}{\sqrt{5} \left(2 x^2+\sqrt{5} x+x+2\right)}+\frac{-2 x+\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{5} \left(2 x^2-\sqrt{5} x+x+2\right)}$